# C++ using this pointer with bind inside lambda function

Tags: c++, lambda, this, bind

I am using std::bind to bind a member function inside a lambda function, in some code like this:

```
class A {
...
...

public:
   foo(function<void()> f) {

   }
...
...
};

class B {
...
...
A a;
public:
   B_function_1(){
      a.foo([](){
         some_other_function(bind(&B::B_function_2, this, _1,_2));
   }
...
private:
   B_function_2(arg1, arg2) {
   ...
   }
};
```

My problem is when I try to compile I have this error:

```
error: ‘this’ was not captured for this lambda function
```

And in my case, this refers to the current class (class B). 
So, my question is what is the problem here? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: The error message says it right there. `this` is not captured. You need to capture it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To capture the this pointer in a lambda you use `a.foo([this]()`

[this] captures the this pointer by value
[&] captures all automatic variables odr-used in the body of the lambda by reference

from the docs

Comment: yeah was in process ofrepasting in. was trying to copy paste from docs :)

Comment: [] Capture nothing (or, a scorched earth strategy?)
[&] Capture any referenced variable by reference
[=] Capture any referenced variable by making a copy
[=, &foo] Capture any referenced variable by making a copy, but capture variable foo by reference
[bar] Capture bar by making a copy; don't copy anything else
[this] Capture the this pointer of the enclosing class